# How to remove edges from ContourPlot3D?

Tags: plotting

The help for ContourPlot3D gives an example like this:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> {Red, Orange, Yellow}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

I've tried using EdgeForm[None]

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> EdgeForm[None], Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

but I still get the edges:

[image]

What is the correct syntax to remove the edges in this case?

Comment: `BoundaryStyle -> None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As wxffles suggested in a comment, add the option `BoundaryStyle -> None,` to your plot.

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
  Mesh -> None,
  ContourStyle -> {Red, Orange, Yellow},
  BoundaryStyle -> None,
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Ah Boundary! That's thinking outside the box :o)